# Псевдокласы в ie 8 (last-child)

Tags: html, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше реализовать псевдокласс `last-child` в ie-8, а именно аннулировать отступ справа у последнего элемента навигационного меню. Корректно ли решить данную проблему с помощью JQuery?

```
var x = $('nav').children().last();
    x.css('margin', '0');
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте! Корректно. Только не забудьте поместить это в отдельный файл и подключать по мере надобности:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/f_ck-old-ie.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

все браузеры, кроме IE<=8, этот скрипт загружать не будут.

Comment: Не за что =) А вообще, необходимость в last-child/first-child в случаях с отступами часто можно обойти. Если бы вопрос содержал пример Вашего кода, может быть, мы с Вами смогли бы придумать что-то получше.

Comment: На данный момент вашего ответа более чем достаточно. Еще раз благодарю Вас!